# The volume of my audio system fluctuates

Tags: speakers

The volume of my *CREATIVE Cambridge Soundworks FourPointSurround FPS1600* fluctuates on its own like if a kid was at the volume control and literally played with it. It is ~18 years old, so I believe that some electronic parts might be worn, since random wiggling of any cable does not make the volume fluctuate, nor does the volume fluctuate on its own all the time. It is very random, sometimes it's unbearable, sometimes it doesn't happen for hours at all.

What are the common causes to this effect when we assume the cables and connectors are ok?

I noticed, that while maintaining the *same level of loudness*, the effect is much smaller when speakers are on low and source on high and extreme when speakers are high and source low. An untrained ear might not even notice it, byt since I am familiar with my music library, it always catches me off guard.

What I managed to record here is really an extreme example. PC volume 75%, speaker volume 65%. Interestingly though, I could not reproduce this an hour later with exactly same setup.
https://soundcloud.com/vferko/sets/volume-fluctuation/s-jjgyI9BeXH8
ATTENTION: The volume spikes are **HUGE** and the recordings start at lowest volume, so don't put it on high volume right from the start.

[image]

[teardown](http://www.dansdata.com/speakersets.htm#:%7E:text=Cambridge%20Soundworks%20FourPointSurround)
[image]

If needed, I can provide more detailed photos of the electronics.

PS: I was resoldering a jack connector as it had a pin detached, but it was not the cause of this issue, even though it manifested in a similar way.

Comment: I might be the capacitors: check if stuff is oozing out of the tops of the electrolytics.

Comment: This might be better answered on engineering.SE, or mechanics.SE. Why would a music fan have any clue how to repair or service the apparatus necessary for music?

Answer (score 2):

FPS 1600 volume control. Followed a Forum tip, disconnected power from volume control then turned volume to full then off several times and problem cured. Been good for 2 months